# To 'confirm' or to 'affirm' a finding, anecdotally?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I just saw this come across my Twitter feed:

> RT @hackernewsbot: Your Commute Is
>   Killing You...
>   http://www.slate.com/id/2295603/pagenum/all/
>   **My two + hours every day [confirm](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3aconfirm)
>   this...**

That made me question for a moment if [*affirm*](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3aaffirm) would be preferred here? They seem like very similar words, and from the definitions I viewed I could make an argument either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Confirm](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/confirm) means to check or establish the truth of some assertion; to [affirm](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/affirm) means to assert or testify the truth of something.

Using *confirm* in the sentence means "my experience is evidence or proof that your two-hour commute is..."; I'm not quite sure what using *affirm* would mean: "my two-hour commute asserts strongly"; I can't quite see how a two-hour commute could do such a thing; it would, I think, be trying to jam too much into the meaning *To support or uphold the validity of; confirm* which would normally mean a person doing so.

Comment: I would even go further to say that only people can affirm something. Objects, or events may confirm my affirmation, but they are incapable of affirming themselves.

Comment: @Sam, pithily put.

Comment: +1, but why "check"? To check something is to *try* to confirm?

Comment: @Cerberus, I think the capital of Mongolia is Ulan Bator; I check the atlas, confirming it. Or don't I?

Comment: Ehh, I suppose they are very close. In many contexts they are interchangeable. I am trying to think of a counter example but it is hard. "Oh, I thought it was Paris? Let me check whether it is Paris or whatever you said." If you are about to confirm something, you already assume that it is true; if you're going to to check it, you don't assume that it's true yet. At least not always, as it is with *confirm*.